# powerbi Web.Contents Error 400

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have request

`NonWorkHours = Web.Contents("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net" & "/api/v1.0/Report/Setter5", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer xxx"]])`

This request works fine in PowerBI Desktop. Authorization is hard coded, so I use Anonymous authorization, but after publishing report I always get `400: Bad request error`.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This an annoying known issue.  You are right to be confused, the web service should work the same way as Power BI Desktop.  The root cause is extra code analysis run silently by the web service.  However it is quite dumb (really pointless) and can be defeated by faking a static URL.

Looking at your code, it might work if you just pass the first parameter to Web.Contents as a single string (remove the & ).

If you requirements are actually more complicated, here are a couple of blog posts that explain other techniques:

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/23/web-contents-m-functions-and-dataset-refresh-errors-in-power-bi/

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2018/02/17/dynamic-web-contents-and-power-bi-refresh-errors/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

let
apiUrl = "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net" & "/api/v1.0/Report/Setter5",

```
options = [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer xxx"]],

result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, options))
```

in

```
result
```